# If Azure App Service swaps physical memory should hangfire restart my job when it is not finished?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, hangfire

We have an azure appservice with some long running processes that are started by hangfire, during these processes the physical memory and CPU's are swapped. This results in cancellations in hangfire. According to the [documentation hangfire](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-cancellation-tokens.html#cancellationtoken) I can give a cancellation.None with the job which is replace internal by hangfire. Should a non finished job then be restarted?

And also why are the memory swaps happening? Is this some king of load balancing which I can Influence?

[memory swap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYQOT.png)

Answer (score 0):

What App Service Plan (ASP) are you leveraging? To isolate the issue, kindly try these steps:

Kindly check if recycle events are happening due to auto-healing or auto-auto healing due to memory in EventLog.xml. As mentioned in this document
[Auto-Healing Windows Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com//blog/auto-healing-windows-azure-web-sites/)

With Auto healing, it can automatic recycle the worker process hosting your web application. When that happens, it will also log an event in eventlog.xml file *(found in Logfiles folder of your web root directory)*.

- Since in an ASP, multiple Apps can be run. To isolate the issue, host the site with sufficient CPU and memory resource, see if it’s feasible to separate the problematic WebApp from other apps (if you’re running multiple apps in the same ASP)
- If the `Always On` setting is off, please enable it from Azure Portal – Your WebApp > Configuration blade (> General settings).
- If you’re leveraging lower ASP SKU/tier, scale-up to a higher tier and then test.

--To fetch more details about the issue/, you may try these:

- You may leverage **App Service diagnostics** from Azure Portal> Navigate to your App Service app in the Azure Portal. (screenshot
  below)
  -- In the left navigation, click on `Diagnose and solve problems` - Review - “Configuration and Management and “Availability and Performance” ||“Web App down” and “Web App Restarted” options.
- Just to highlight, SSE uses long-polling requests, it may hit the
  230s limit. Azure Load Balancer has a default idle timeout setting of four minutes (~230 secs). If your web app requires background
  processing, it is recommended to use Azure WebJobs or Azure
  Functions.

--Review the logs as outlined in this documentation:

[Enable diagnostics logging for apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#access-log-files)

[Proactive Auto Heal](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2017/08/17/Introducing-Proactive-Auto-Heal.html)

[image: App Service Diagnostics]